# How do I prove that the only possible function is $exp$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, logarithms

Let´s say we have a differentiable function

$f :  \mathbb{R} ->   \mathbb{R}$

with

$f' = f$

and

$f(0) = 1$ .

How do I show that the only possible function for this to work
$f = exp$   ?

From    $f' = f  $

I concluded that

$1  = \frac{1}{f} \cdot f'  => (ln(f))' $

If we define

$ g' := (ln(f))$

Then we know that

$ g= exp(f)$

But I´m stuck right there. How do I go on?

Comment: The integral of $ln(f)$ _is not_ $\exp(f)$. If $g = ln(f) \implies e^{g} = f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(\ln f)' = 1$, by integration, $\ln f(x)= x + C$, where $C$ is a constant. Using the condition $f(0) = 1$, we find that $C = 0$. Hence, $\ln f(x) = x$, i.e., $f(x) = \exp(x)$.

Note: Since you were not given that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ from the start, perhaps a safer way to approach the problem is to consider the function $g(x) := f(x) \exp(-x)$. By the chain rule, $$g'(x) = f'(x)\exp(-x) - f(x)\exp(-x) = (f'(x) - f(x))\exp(-x) = 0$$ Hence, $g(x)$ is constant. Since $f(0) = 1$, $g(0) = 1$. Therefore, $g(x) = 1$, i.e., $f(x) = \exp(x)$.

For uniqueness, suppose $f_1$ and $f_2$ satisfy the initial value problem $f' - f = 0$, $f(0) = 1$. Then $f_1 - f_2$ satisfy the differential equation with $(f_1 - f_2)(0) = 0$. Hence, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f_1(x) - f_2(x) = 0$, i.e., $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$.

Comment: I understand what you wrote but is it proven that $exp(x)$ is the only possible solution?

Comment: Im sorry but could you explain the shortforms? e.g. ODE

Comment: I've removed the abbreviations so it'll be easier for you to follow.

Comment: How did you come up with the definition of $g(x)$?

Comment: Since the goal was to prove that $f(x) = \exp(x)$ is the solution, and $f(x) = \exp(x)$ if and only if $f(x)\exp(-x) = 1$, letting $g(x) = f(x)\exp(-x)$, I just have to show that $g$ is constant (by proving $g' = 0$) with $g(0) = 1$.

Comment: Alright I got it. Thank you for the fast answer :)